# Typescript - initialize a 2D array ERROR

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2D array for coordinates like [[x_1,y_1,z_1], [x_2,y_2,z_2], [...],...].

Here is my code for initialization and initial declaration:

```
var ALLcoordinates:number[][];

for (var i=0; i< dims; i++) {
    ALLcoordinates[i]=[];
    for (var j=0; j<chainSize; j++){
        ALLcoordinates[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

After that, I assign new values for each row in this loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < chainSize; i++) {
    var alea1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-0+1))+0;
    var alea2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-0+1))+0;
    var alea3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-0+1))+0;
    var coordinates:number[];
    coordinates = [alea1,alea2,alea3];
    ALLcoordinates[i]=coordinates;

}
```

But when I compile it, I get this error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` for this line `ALLcoordinates[i] = [];`

I would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Is this typescript or javascript? This is not the right way to declare variables in typescript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you did `var ALLcoordinates:number[][];`, you did not initialize it with any value. You just specified its type. It will still be `undefined` at runtime. So `undefined[0]` throws the error. Initialize it before using it:

```
var ALLcoordinates: number[][] = [];
```

Answer (score 7):

Declaring an array does not initialize  it.

You are missing the `ALLcoordinates` initialization:

```
var ALLcoordinates:number[][];

ALLcoordinates = [];            //  ◄ initialize the array

for (var i=0; i< dims; i++) {
    ALLcoordinates[i]=[];
    for (var j=0; j<chainSize; j++){
        ALLcoordinates[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```